# Send data from one DialogFragment to another in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-camera-intent, dialogfragment

I have three fragments namely the `AudioRecorderFragment` which is a `Fragment`, `UploadFragment` which is a `DialogFragment` and another `DialogFragment` known as `UploadPhotoDialog`.

A user should record audio from the `AudioRecorderFragment` and then on hitting an upload button, the `UploadFragment` shows. In the `UploadFragment`, the user will enter the details of the recorded audio clip and may include an image. When selecting the image, the `UploadPhotoDialog` fragment shows up and the user can select whether to take a photo using the camera or pick one from gallery. My problem is how to get the selection from the `UploadPhotoDialog` back to the `UploadFragment`. I am not getting a result. Also when I try to call a camera intent from the `UploadFragment`, I get a null pointer exception  in the

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}
```

on the fileUri ... line whenever i want to show the fragment from my AudioRecorderFragment. How can I solve this?
Here is my `UploadFragment` code:

```
public class UploadFragment extends DialogFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {
    Spinner genres;
ImageView photo;
TextView submit;
String fileName="";

private static final String KEY="choice";

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload, null);
    builder.setView(v);

    submit = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.upload_textView_submit);
    genres = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.upload_spinner_genre);
    photo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.upload_imageView_photo);

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.ngoma_spinner, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.genres));
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    genres.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if(bundle != null){
        fileName = bundle.getString("arg_fileName");
    }

    genres.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    photo.setOnClickListener(this);
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

private static final int INT_CODE=1;
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.upload_textView_submit:
            getDialog().dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.upload_imageView_photo:
            UploadPhotoDialog uploadDialog = new UploadPhotoDialog();
            uploadDialog.setTargetFragment(this, INT_CODE);
            uploadDialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "uploadPhoto");
            break;
    }
}


/******************************************************************************************************/

private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


/**
 * Select image from gallery
 */
private void selectFromGallery() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}

/**
 * Capturing Camera Image will lauch camera app requrest image capture
 */
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
 * app
 */

// directory name to store captured images and videos
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "ngoma";

private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
    // changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
}

/*
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}*/

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
   // fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}

/**
 * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
 * */
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data);
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // successfully captured the image
            // display it in image view
            previewCapturedImage();
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        // String picturePath contains the path of selected Image
        previewFromGallery(picturePath);
    }

    if (requestCode == INT_CODE) { //make sure fragment codes match up {
        String choice = data.getStringExtra(KEY);

        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("camera")){
            captureImage();
        }

        else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("gallery")){
            selectFromGallery();
        }

    }
    }

/**
 * Display image from a path to ImageView
 */
private void previewCapturedImage() {
    try {

        // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                options);

        photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void previewFromGallery(String picturePath) {
    photo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
}

/**
 * ------------ Helper Methods ----------------------
 * */

/**
 * Creating file uri to store image/video
 */
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/**
 * returning image / video
 */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Error creating "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory.");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

}
```

And the UploadPhotoDialog fragment code

```
public class UploadPhotoDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
LinearLayout fromgallery, fromcamera;
String choice;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_uploadphoto_dialog, null);
    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    choice = "";
    builder.setView(v);

    fromgallery = (LinearLayout) v
            .findViewById(R.id.uploadphoto_gallery_layout);
    fromcamera = (LinearLayout) v
            .findViewById(R.id.uploadphoto_camera_layout);

    fromcamera.setOnClickListener(this);
    fromgallery.setOnClickListener(this);
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.uploadphoto_gallery_layout:
            // Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AudioRecorder.class);
            //startActivity(intent);

            //AudioRecorderFragment audioRecorder= new AudioRecorderFragment();
            //getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,audioRecorder).commit();

            choice ="gallery";
            getDialog().dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.uploadphoto_camera_layout:
            //Intent intentVideo = new Intent(getActivity(), VideoRecorderActivity.class);
            //startActivity(intentVideo);
            choice ="camera";
            getDialog().dismiss();
            break;
    }

}

private static final String KEY="choice";
private static final int INT_CODE=1;

private void sendResult(int INT_CODE) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra(KEY, choice);
    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), INT_CODE, i);
}
}
```

Sorry, I know thats a lot of code but it's my best way of expressing my problem.
Help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you show your fragment you can also pass data through the setArguments function of the fragment or by establishing an Interface between the two fragments, something along the lines:

```
public Interface IReceiveChoice {
   void Selected(int choice);
}
```

then in the class you want to choose you implement IReceiveChoice;

```
public class UploadPhotoDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener, IReceiveChoice {
  @Override 
  public void Selected(int choice) {
     //do stuff
  }
  ....
```

And when you choose in the first activity you find the other activity, cast it to an IReceiveChoice and call the method Selected with your choice.

```
Fragment f = getTargetFragment(); 
if(f != null && f instanceof IReceiveChoice) {
  f.Selected(choice);
}
```

There you have to ensure that the fragment exists but it is an alternative to sending a whole lot of bundles everywhere if your data is small and simple.